# Force a reload of a given URL in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

For most URLs, the key combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> works fine.

But for redirects ([example: a favicon.ico](https://superuser.com/favicon.ico)) it reloads the target URL instead of the one typed into the address bar, and for files that Firefox can't open in-browser ([example: a .TIFF image file](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/55576_Amycus.tiff), or anything that gets a "What should Firefox do with this file?" prompt) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> simply doesn't work.

How do I force a reload of a given URL in Firefox without it doing a redirect or a download for those times when it does?

Answer (score 0):

To force reload: <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: As I said in the OP, this doesn't work for either of the types of URLs I'm trying to reload.

Comment: If I understand your question, the answer is that you can't. If you want to go from the target back to the redirect, you'll have to enter it manually or click back to the original link.

Comment: not that suprising I suppose, but still disappointing (On the plus side, the remaining cache poisoning seems to have died on its own for now.)